# golang template escape first char

Tags: templates, go

I'm trying to build sitemap XML file with the standard template package.
But the first charset "**<**" become "**&lt ;**", and make the XML unreadable for clients.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
)

const (
    tmplStr = `{{define "indexSitemap"}}<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<sitemap>
    <loc>https://www.test.com/sitemap.xml</loc>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
    <loc>https://www.test.com/events-sitemap.xml</loc>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
    <loc>https://www.test.com/gamesAndTeams-sitemap.xml</loc>
</sitemap>
</sitemapindex>{{end}}`
)

func main() {
    // Parse the template and check for error
    tmpl, parseErr := template.New("test").Parse(tmplStr)
    if parseErr != nil {
        fmt.Println(parseErr)
        return
    }

    // Init the writer
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)

    // Execute and get the template error if any
    tmplExErr := tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(buf, "indexSitemap", nil)
    if tmplExErr != nil {
        fmt.Println(tmplExErr)
        return
    }

    // Print the content malformed
    fmt.Println(buf)
}
```

[playground golang](http://play.golang.org/p/PUylzjxJfW)

Is that normal?
How can I make it works normaly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you using `text/template` or `html/template`?

Answer (score 2):

Your example shows you're using the `html/template` package, which auto-escapes text for html usage.

If you want a raw template engine, use the `text/template` package instead - the html one just wraps it with context-aware escaping.

However, you'll need to make sure by yourself that the texts you output with the raw template engine are XML-safe. You can do this by exposing some `escape` function to your template, and passing all texts via this function instead of writing them directly.

**[EDIT]** It looks like a bug in `html/template`, if you omit the `?` from the xml declaration it works okay. But still my advice stands - if it's not html you're better off using the `text/template` package. Actually, even better, describe the site map as a struct and don't use a template at all, just XML serialization.

Comment: If you want an example of exposing an XML escaping function to the template I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: I was thinking that only values past into the template was escape.
So my bad.

Thanks

Comment: @AlexandreStein it actually looks like a bug, but using the text/template will still fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Also see issue #12496 on github which confirms they are not planning to fix this.

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12496

> Probably because this is the HTML templating package and you're trying
>   to produce XML. I suspect that it doesn't know how to parse the 
>   directives with the question mark there.
>
> You probably want to use the text/template package instead, if you're
>   not going to be taking advantage of any of the HTML auto-escaping
>   features.